# DevOps missing environment variables

Tags: .net, azure-devops

We are using the DevOps 2019 build server and some of the build definitions do not contain the following environment variables:

SOLUTION_FILEPATH

SOLUTION_SOURCEPATH

In these build definitions the BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH value is $/

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Why do you think there should be variables named `SOLUTION_FILEPATH` and `SOLUTION_SOURCEPATH`? Those are not listed in the documentation as predefined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, we can know that you can call SOLUTION_FILEPATH and SOLUTION_SOURCEPATH environment variables in some build definitions. You can first check if you have customized these two environment variables in some tasks so that you can call them in some build definitions.

After testing, SOLUTION_FILEPATH and SOLUTION_SOURCEPATH are not predefined variables, they cannot be recognized. In addition, you can't find these two environment variables from the [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) document.

[image]

So in summary, these two environment variables should be customized by you , if the build definitions do not contain these two environment variables , it should be because you did not set them.